# Inconsistent Regex Results

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
values.communicators.forEach(e => {
    let isValid = /(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d].*)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$&-. )(:]{2,}/gi.test(e.name);
    console.log(isValid)
    if (!isValid) {
        errors.communicators = 'Unsupported character or length in communicator names.'
    }
})
```

When I use the like above in code something like `Some Diddy∞∞` will pass but at https://regexr.com/ it will not.

Does anyone know what may be going on?

Comment: It will on regexr.com too. If you need to test on entire input string you should add `^` and `$` anchors: `^REGEX$`

Comment: So I'm curious: does PHP require this too? Also what does it check against without `^` and `$`? @revo

Comment: PHP needs it to match against whole input string as well. When those anchors are not available a partial match may happen that satisfies engine but doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: You might be getting hit with the `lastIndex` attr that plagues many unsuspecting devs when working with the `g` flag.